# Is there a proper way to translate a specific javascript statement to java?

Tags: java, javascript, coding-style

I'm translating a program from JavaScript to Java SE.

I found this statement in JavaScript:

```
var ROAD = {
  LENGTH: { NONE: 0, SHORT:  25, MEDIUM:  50, LONG:  100 },
  CURVE:  { NONE: 0, EASY:    2, MEDIUM:   4, HARD:    6 }
};
```

I translated it with the following Java classes:

```
public class Road {
public static final LengthLevel LENGTH = new LengthLevel();
public static final CurveLevel CURVE = new CurveLevel();
}

class LengthLevel {
public static final int NONE   = 0,
                        SHORT  = 25,
                        MEDIUM = 50,
                        LONG   = 100;
}

class CurveLevel {
public static final int NONE   = 0,
                        EASY   = 2,
                        MEDIUM = 4,
                        HARD   = 6;
}
```

I got several warnings from Netbeans 8:

a) Inside the class Road the warning is "Exporting non-public type through public API".

b) While using the constants elsewhere, e.g.

```
Road.LENGTH.MEDIUM
```

the warning is "Accessing static field MEDIUM" and "Replace with class reference".

Now, I understand the meaning of the warnings. And I know that they will disappear if both LengthLevel and CurveLevel are declared as public in their own files.

Thus, my specific question is if there is a less verbose way of translating the original Javascript statement.

Thanks,

Comment: Creating a new `XxxLevel` is pointless since you only have static values. There are any number of ways of translating this, including a map of some sort, enums, etc. It depends on your usecase. Will any be less verbose? Not significantly, no.

Comment: Is using Groovy an option? Java does tend to be a bit verbose compared to scripting languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public class Road {
    public enum LENGTH {
        NONE(0), SHORT(25), MEDIUM(50), LONG(100);
        private final int length;

        LENGTH(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return length;
        }
    }

    public enum CURVE {
        NONE(0), EASY(2), MEDIUM(4), HARD(6);
        private final int curve;

        CURVE(int curve) {
            this.curve = curve;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return curve;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the value using the following method call:

```
        int longLength = Road.LENGTH.LONG.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks. The warnings disappeared. I think this is the closest to the original syntax that Java can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you are really attached to referring to the values in the same way as in Javascript you could do something like this (whether it's great code is another question):

```
public class Road {
    public static final _LENGTH LENGTH = new _LENGTH();
    private static class _LENGTH {
        public static final int NONE = 0;
        public static final int SHORT = 25;
        public static final int MEDIUM = 50;
        public static final int LONG = 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example access
        System.out.println(Road.LENGTH.LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The warnings did not disappear. Moreover, the access Road.LENGTH.LONG gives and error about LONG being unreachable.